# Microservices jwt authentication Asp.net core 3

Tags: docker, jwt, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I got a confusion about making security of our micro-services with JWT (token)

I created a micro-service that gives me the token in response but what about the other micro-services

**is it a correct way to pass the token in header request to each endpoint of each micro-service ?**

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the recommended way is to have an API gateway in place which can contact this micro-service you already have issuing JWT tokens and then it can add the token to the header of the request to the actual API call being made.

An API gateway provides highly available and thin layer between the client and micro services. One such API gateway which I can recommend: https://docs.traefik.io

Specifically, you can read about this section: https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/forwardauth/

And a blog on the same which can guide you with a working example: [here](https://medium.com/@akazuko/authn-and-authz-with-traefik-for-micro-services-1746ca6ee4d1?source=friends_link&sk=071e4f81c069650a061f9b0d7637dd82)

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to my question  for that i did not mark as a correct answer : 
is it a correct way to pass the token in header request to each endpoint of each micro-service ?

Comment: IMO should be passed to each micro-service as token can be used to infer the user information (only an identifier) and thus enabling you to solve distributed session among multiple instances of services